# Introspection during Rails Test Execution -- How?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, introspection, testunit

I am generating some output files during the execution of rails tests, and I would like to be able to name the files based on the current test class and current test method.  Is there a way to get this information built into Test::Unit?  Is there some clever way to get this from inside the test methods?  I can get the current method name by calling **method**, but I can't figure out how to get the current class name.

Calling self.class returns Controller, not the actual test class ( PostTest, for example ).

Comment: is this still an open issue for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should return your class name in unit test:

```
  test "class name" do
    puts "#{self.class.name}"
  end
```

Are you saying this is not working for you? It should work.